# Add 'Watermark' to images with php _code

Tags: php, html, image, watermark

I have a website where users may upload images...

I need to add my logo (watermark) to the images every single time to  uploaded.

How can I do so?

Anybody have a good tutorial, article or example for this? Or know of any function in php which I would need to find the position of the watermark?

```
<?php
if(houzez_edit_property()) {
    $property_images = get_post_meta( $property_data->ID, 'fave_property_images', false );

    $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $property_data->ID );
    $property_images[] = $featured_image_id;
    $property_images = array_unique($property_images);

    if (!empty($property_images[0])) {
        foreach ($property_images as $prop_image_id) {
            $is_featured_image = ($featured_image_id == $prop_image_id);
            $featured_icon = ($is_featured_image) ? 'text-success' : '';

            $img_available = wp_get_attachment_image($prop_image_id, 'thumbnail');

            if (!empty($img_available)) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6 property-thumb">';
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($prop_image_id, 'houzez-item-image-1', false, array('class' => 'img-fluid'));
                echo '<div class="upload-gallery-thumb-buttons">';
                echo '<button class="icon icon-fav icon-featured" data-property-id="' . intval($property_data->ID) . '" data-attachment-id="' . intval($prop_image_id) . '"><i class="houzez-icon icon-rating-star full-star '.esc_attr($featured_icon).'"></i></button>';

                echo '<button class="icon icon-delete" data-property-id="' . intval($property_data->ID) . '" data-attachment-id="' . intval($prop_image_id) . '"><span class="btn-loader houzez-loader-js"></span><i class="houzez-icon icon-remove-circle"></i></button>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<input type="hidden" class="propperty-image-id" name="propperty_image_ids[]" value="' . intval($prop_image_id) . '"/>';

                if ($is_featured_image) {
                    echo '<input type="hidden" class="featured_image_id" name="featured_image_id" value="' . intval($prop_image_id) . '">';
                }
                                
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) have you done? There are plenty of articles/guides about that out there. (Asking for recommendations/suggestions about tutorials/libraries etc are unfortunately off-topic here)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP GD Library. You can open saved image file, write text or overlay watermark image and save image again.